# Store data in two pages from one form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am thinking about storing data into a database and into another web page with this html code:

```
<form name="form" method="post"  action="Process Clients.php", "budgets.php">
```

Is it possible? If it is not, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: oh it's magic ... hidden html code ;) ... but you need serverside code to write it into a database

Comment: jajaja sorry for the code! I have already put it into the database but now I want to put into the two sites and I was thinking about doing it in this way

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a server-side language. In order to write to a database (which lives on a server), you will need a server-side language.

Your HTML is the beginnings of posting form data to a PHP file. Therefore, I can assume you are planning on using PHP...? PHP is indeed a server-side language.

There are many ways to write to a database using PHP, but it depends what database software you are using. Consider using [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) if you are planning on using MySQL or maybe [MsSql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) if you are using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL, concretely the phpmyadmin database. I alredy created a .php file to post it in the database and I am creating an other to put the data given in the html form into a budget table. My idea is that when you click on the html file button "submit", a pup up appears and it shows the busgets table at the same time that the daata is stored in the database

Comment: If you are using the same form data, you shouldn't need two php files. One php file can write all the queries youd like. Try returning a `SELECT` query in the form of JSON.

Comment: OK, thank you! I have made what you said, in the same .php file that I use to send the data to the database I created a table, stored the variables and puted an echo, but it prints a blanc space, not the form value... 

    $Fecha = '$_POST[Fecha]';

    <tr>

    <td colspan="2"><strong>Fecha:</strong></td>

    <td <?php echo $Fecha ?> width="93" class="datos">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in two table can be done by one PHP page. But if you want to update in two different MySQL instance then there are two case:

1- If you have access of both instance from same PHP server you can update data by single PHP file by make two different connection through `mysqli_connect()`.

2- If both instances on different server then you need to call two different PHP script which are placed on both different servers. Then follow options below:

There are two methods: using **cURL** to send post var to another page (Budgets.php) from first (ProcessClients.php) OR **ajax** on HTML to send post request to both pages.

**cURL:** this link to setup cURL-> [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php)

In ProcessClients.php file write at end:

`$url = 'http://URL/Budgets.php';
    $fields = array(
      'field1' => $_POST["var1"],
      'field2' => $_POST["var2"],
    );
    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);
    //----------------
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    //----------------
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);`

--------------------**OR**------------------------

**AJAX:**

In form add simple button input not submit, like this:

`<form name='f' method='post'>
     <input name='var1' type='text' />
      <input type='button' value="upload" onclick='sendTo2Pages();' />
     </form>`

Then Write JavaScript function:

`function sendTo2Pages(){
     var parameters="var1="+f.var1.value+"&var2="+f.var2.value;
     //----------------
     var xmlhttp="";
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             //perform operation on success and response var is: xmlhttp.responseText
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("POST",'http://URL/ProcessClient.php',true);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlhttp.send(parameters);
     //---------------------------------
     var xmlhttp2="";
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
     else xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     xmlhttp2.open("POST",'http://URL2/Budgets.php',true);
     xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlhttp2.send(parameters);
     }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Adarsh! But I think it will be easier to use only one .php file and create there the table that I wanted to create into the other .php file. The code I used is only php and it is this:
$Fecha = '$_POST[Fecha]'; <tr> <td colspan="2"><strong>Fecha:</strong></td> <td <?php echo $Fecha ?> width="93" class="datos">&nbsp;</td> </tr>

But it prints me a white space instead of the data... Elliot said me I have to use JQuery but I know nothing of it language... Could you put some code and I try if it works? 

Thanks

Comment: @user3894819 I replied coz, it may help to others. Your code seems to me wrong. `<?php $Fecha=$_POST['Fecha']; ?> <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Fecha:</strong></td> <td width="93" class="datos"><?php echo $Fecha ?></td> </tr>`. You was echoing $Fecha inside TD tag and content was an just space(&nbsp; -> code of blank space). And at starting of line inverted comma should be insite [] to wrap 'Fecha'.

Comment: I have tried to delete "&nbsp" and to put $Fecha = $_POST['Fecha']; instead of $Fecha = '$_POST[Fecha]' but now it says: Undefined index: Fecha in C:\wamp\www\SIENS\Presupuestos\Process Presupuestos.php on line 61. (In the form I have it corerctly, I have: name = Fecha)

Comment: @user3894819 Check form method correctly it should be `method='post'` and input name='Fecha' then on submit it will work. And also an suggestion, don't use SPACE in PHP file names, it should be ProcessPresupuestos.php.

Comment: Ok, I know more or less what is the problem: after doing what you say, it appears: Undefined index: Fecha in C:\wamp\www\SIENS\Presupuestos\Process Presupuestos.php on line 61 but if I click back page and I click submit another time, the values are printed correctly but appears: Duplicate entry. 
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @user3894819 while testing each time you need to go back and submit. With this less info I cant tell you exact solution. It is printing 'Duplicate Entry' on page or showing Fecha 2 times?? Show me the printing code?? If you are inserting $Fecha in database and don't want to be duplicate then make Fecha column as a unique index OR check, weather it exist or not in table, before inserting.